# Two sql tables with same id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Im trying to achieve something what is, i think easy, but i cant figure out how to do it. Im working in MySql database.

I have main table named `MyGuests` with AI `id_guests` and second table named `Information` with AI `id_info` and non AI `id_guests`. I would like to have the `id_guests` in `Information` table have the same value as `id_guests` in `MyGuests` table.

Basicly im trying to link the Information table to MyGuests table with IDs. Ive tried foreign key, but somehow the id in information table is always 0.
Maybe im doing something wrong, i dont know... Ive done this:

```
ALTER TABLE Information ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_guests) REFERENCES MyGuests(id_guests);
```

If somebody could tell me what am i doing wrong or tell me how to do it, i would be really thankfull

Comment: I don't really understand the question, do you want the database to magically understand which values to reference?

Comment: I want id columm in second table to have the same value as id columm in first table. I dont know how else to describe it :/

Comment: Well, you do that when inserting a value. You insert a value in the second table that exists in the first table.

Comment: So i have to select id from first table and then insert into second? Im beginner in sql so its im not sure

Comment: Probably, yeah...

Comment: Please read and act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a constraint on existing column of the same type of which it will be a foreign key.

```
alter table Information add constraint fk_id_guests foreign key(id_guests) references MyGuests (id_guests)
```

The columns should be the equals both table.

```
alter table MyGuests modify id_guests int(5) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT

alter table Information modify id_guests int(5) not null
```

Getting the last ID was inserted in table.

```
$query = "insert into MyGuests(id_guests) values (1)";

mysqli_query($conn, $query)

$id_guests = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

$query = "insert into Information(id_guests)values(".$id_guests.")";
```

Comment: Well... thanks for advice, but im still getting 0 in the Information table. I pasted those two rows to make them equal, set the first id to be AI and after that i pasted the constraint row. Still not working :(

Comment: Try use `SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;` or `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`

Comment: Nothing... i guess i will have to do it with select and insert then? :/

Comment: I have insert.php which triggers after button is pressed (there i have INSERT commands). For table edit etc. i use phpMyAdmin.... if this is what you asked for

Comment: I changed my sample, look and tell me if help you.

Comment: Would it be problem if i sent you a link to google docs and you looked at it? Because if i do as you said, i get error with duplicated primary keys, because the id in MyGuests is not AutoIncrement. When i set to as AI it keeps giving me 0 in Information table

Comment: No problem, send me the link.

Comment: insert.php 

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LLUxTKU1nLyRN6oiwF6wdARcEqhso69PGaHZlisPD1Y/edit?usp=sharing